# Error When Using Chalkboard in Redhawk IDE Sandbox

Tags: redhawksdr

I'm trying to test components in the Sandbox using the REDHAWK IDE but I receive an error every time I to drag a component on to the Chalkboard.

For example, when I try to drag the built in SigGen component on to the Chalkboard I get a popup window stating:

```
'Launching component SigGen_1' has encountered a problem.

Failed to launch: SigGen_1
```

In the details section it says:

```
Failed to launch: SigGen_1
IDL:CD/ExecutableDevice/ExecuteFail:1.0
```

Also, the error in console window depends on the implementation I launch (the error in the pop window remains the same). For Java, no error is displayed in the console window. The errors from C++ and Python implementations are below.

C++

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CORBA::TRANSIENT'
```

Python

```
ERROR:root:Unexpected Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/redhawk/core/lib/python/ossie/resource.py", line 538, in start_component
    rootContext.rebind(name, component_Var)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/omniORB/COS/CosNaming_idl.py", line 222, in rebind
    return _omnipy.invoke(self, "rebind", _0_CosNaming.NamingContext._d_rebind, args)
TRANSIENT: CORBA.TRANSIENT(omniORB.TRANSIENT_ConnectFailed, CORBA.COMPLETED_NO)
```

The SigGen component does not even show on the Chalkboard in the IDE.

When I try to launch waveforms in the REDHAWK_DEV domain I don't encounter any problems.

Comment: Are you getting this error with every implementation of SigGen (cpp, python, and java)? Or with a specific one?

Comment: I receive errors with all implementations (C++, Java, and Python). The question was edited to provide more details on the errors for other implementations.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this, but it may be an issue with your router blocking some of the omniORB ports. Try disconnecting your network and connecting to a 'dummy' network that connects to nothing. Then try dragging a component into your chalkboard.

Comment: I disabled my firewall, but the same error occurs. What do you mean connect to a dummy network? Also, why would anything be sent to the network router? Wouldn't the Sandbox use localhost as the address for everything?

Comment: Not exactly sure what would cause this but since it is an omniORB exception being thrown I'd recommend raising your omniORB debug level in order to get some additional information about this issue.  See the following post for information on how to output additional debug info http://stackoverflow.com/a/20476603/2391144  Comment back with any additional information or if you solve it, let us know what the issue was.

Comment: Is this on RedHawk 1.9?

Comment: Yes, it is on Redhawk 1.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem initially. I am running CentOS 6.4 with Redhawk 1.9. I had to add an entry in my /etc/hosts file due to the fact that I named my computer something other than localhost. I just added a line such as:

```
127.0.0.1    YourComputersHostName
```

to /etc/hosts replacing YourComputersHostName with your computers actual hostname.

Comment: It worked! The only additional step I had to take was restart the REDHAWK IDE after I changed the /etc/hosts file. However, I don't understand why this fix worked. I guess it's possible that the omniORB ports are being blocked somewhere in my network chain and that adding my hostname to the /etc/hosts file allows me to avoid all other firewalls external to my computer.